# Quickest way to change dir from /xxxxx/foo/yyyyyy to /xxxxx/bar/yyyyyy

Tags: bash

Using bash, what is the easiest way to 'replace' a given part of the current path with something else?  If my current path is of the form `/xxxxx/foo/yyyyy`, how can I jump to the `/xxxxx/bar/baz/yyyyy` directory with the shortest command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage a shell function to provide you this ability as needed:

```
change() { path=`pwd`; cd `echo $path | sed "s/$1/$2/"`; }
```

Which would be called from /foo/bar/ as:

```
change "bar" "gazi"
```

Please note that the "'s are not required for this example, but would be required for special strings such as directories with space character(s) in the name.

Comment: Added `function cdd(){ cd ${PWD/$1/$2}; }` to my `.bashrc`. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this works always correctly. E.g. it would change the path from `/foosomething/foo` into `/bar/bazsomething/bar/baz`.

Answer (score 3):

Not so short, but works: `cd ${PWD/foo/bar\/baz}`

Answer (score 2):

```
cd ../../bar/baz/yyyyy
cd $(echo $PWD | sed 's|foo|bar/baz|')
```

The second one looks "cooler" but the first one is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh: `cd foo bar`

In bash: `` cd `zsh -ci 'cd foo bar'` ``
which can be shortened to `` `zsh -ci 'cd foo bar'` `` under `shopt -s autocd` in bash ≥4. Add double quotes around the backquotes if the resultin. This only works if zsh prints a directory without `~` abbreviations; alternatively, `zsh -c 'cd foo bar;pwd'` prints a path with abbreviations but it starts getting long.

In bash, you could write a wrapper around the `cd` builtin that emulates the zsh behavior.

```
cd () {
  local -a opts
  opts=()
  while [[ $1 = -* ]]; do opts=("${opts[@]}" "$1"); shift; done
  if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    set -- "${PWD/$1/$2}"
  fi
  if [[ ${#opts[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    set -- "${opts[@]}" "$@"
  fi
  builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Comment: Heh, `cd \`zsh -ci 'cd foo bar'\`` -- I am very amused by this for some reason.

Comment: @Random832 http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=295833#295833

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you changed to `/xxxxx/foo/yyyyy` with `cd /xxxxx/foo/yyyyy` and want to change directly after this command to the other directory, you could use `!!:s/foo/bar\/baz/`. Which means, repeat the last command, but replace `foo` with `bar/baz`.

When you executed some commands between the two `cd`s, you could use `!cd:s/foo/bar\/baz/`. Whichs means, repeat last `cd` command and replace.

For some more examples and history commands, take a look at the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively).

Answer (score 0):

To add to this concept of using the history, I recommend looking into the [pushd and popd](http://eriwen.com/bash/pushd-and-popd/) commands in bash, which can very easily switch between the stored directories. The blog link is also a very nice resource for other methods of directory switching, including comments on how to do this within a script.